# Functional assertion in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, assert

Is there built-in support for assertions that return a result?

It is very non-functional to do this:

```
  def addPositive(a: Int, b: Int) = {
    assert(a > 0 && b > 0)
    a + b
  }
```

I would rather do something similar to:

```
  def addPositive(a: Int, b: Int) = 
    assert(a > 0 && b > 0)(a + b)
```

In this way I can avoid the imperative aspect of asserts. (the latter does not compile)
Is anything similar available?

Comment: By the way, there is *post* condition: [`Predef.ensuring`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L49).

Comment: Yes, I found that too. But what I need is a precondition.

Comment: The main idea behind `assert` is that it throws exception when your condition is not met. Throwing exception is a very non-functional thing to do. Assertions are imperative by nature. Trying to make them more functional seems strange to me.

Comment: @johnsullivan *Catching* exceptions is imperative in nature. *Throwing* an exception is just a way of failing to compute a result, just like looping forever.

Comment: Do you *want* it to throw an exception?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Functional programming treats functions as pure mathematical functions (ideally). So what's the mathematics' way of saying a function doesn't work for some parameters and must blow up ?

[**Partial Functions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function)

It turns out that Scala has a pretty good support for this concept: [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction).
This is how you would rewrite your code using partial functions:

```
val addPositive: PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int] = {
  case (a, b) if a > 0 && b > 0 => a + b
}
```

This has several benefits:

If you call it with the wrong parameters it will throw a `MatchError` exception.

```
addPositive(-1, 2) => Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: (-1,2) (of class scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp)
```

You can actually sample the function's domain to check if some values are well suited as arguments for the function:

```
addPositive.isDefinedAt(-1, 2) => false
```

If you would like to apply the function to some arguments and get either a result, or some value indicating failure, you can `lift` it to return `Option`

```
addPositive.lift(-1, 2) => None
addPositive.lift(1, 2) => Some(12)
```

You can compose it with other functions to provide fallback in case of invalid arguments:

```
val fallback: PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int] = { case (a, b) => Int.MinValue }
val f = addPositive orElse fallback

f(-1, 2) => -2147483648
```

Or to treat errors in a custom way:

```
val raiseError: PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int] = {
  case (a, b) => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Cannot apply addPositive to arguments $a and $b")
}
val g = addPositive orElse raiseError

g(-1, 2) => Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot apply addPositive to arguments -1 and 2
```

It works well with the standard lib: see `Seq.collect` and `Seq.collectFirst`.

Also `PartialFunction` is a normal unary function, so you inherit all the function operation as well.

Here is an article explaining very elegantly partial functions in Scala:

[**Scala partial functions (without a PhD)**](http://blog.bruchez.name/2011/10/scala-partial-functions-without-phd.html)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to answer this question more correctly. Great!

Comment: Very good, thank you. The only bad thing is that it is quite verbose. But you show some very good points and answered my question nicely!

Answer (score 4):

You could roll out your own implementation:

```
def assert[T](cond: =>Boolean)(expr: =>T): T = {
  assert(cond)
  expr
}
```

You could also use the option type to avoid exceptions, but that means that you'd later have to pattern match on the result:

```
def addPositive(a: Int, b: Int): Option[int] =
  if (a > 0 && b > 0) Some(a + b)
  else None
```

This can be refactored in the similar manner as the `assert` variant above.

Comment: Yes. I don't like this very much :) I tend to be very against bringing your own tools around for a language.

Answer (score -5):

There is the `require` function for preconditions, which pretty much accomplishes what you want. You can do

```
def addPositive(a: Int, b: Int) = 
   require (a > 0 && b > 0, a + b)
```

There are part of [scala.Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24), so they are always included. The parameter (`a+b` in the example) is passed by name, so it will only be executed if the condition isn't true.

`requires` is always activated, if you want to be able to deactivate it you can make it with `assert` too, like :

```
assert(a > 0 && b > 0, a + b)
```

Comment: I don't think this does what you think it does.

Comment: It depends on what you think I think: it will throw an 1IllegalArgumentException` with message `requirement failed` plus the value of `a+b`