# Is returning Either/Option/Try/Or considered a viable / idiomatic approach when function has preconditions for arguments?

Tags: scala, error-handling

First of all, I'm very new to Scala and don't have any experience writing production code with it, so I lack understanding of what is considered a good/best practice among community. I stumbled upon these resources:

1. https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices
2. https://nrinaudo.github.io/scala-best-practices/

It is mentioned there that throwing exceptions is not very good practice, which made me think what would be a good way to define preconditions for function then, because

> A function that throws is a bit of a lie: its type implies it’s total function when it’s not.

After a bit of research, it seems that using `Option`/`Either`/`Try`/`Or`(scalactic) is a better approach, since you can use something like `T Or IllegalArgumentException` as return type to clearly indicate that function is actually partial, using exception as a way to store message that can be wrapped in other exceptions.

However lacking Scala experience I don't quite understand if this is actually viable approach for a real project or using `Predef.require` is a way to go. I would appreciate if someone explained how things are usually done in Scala community and why.

I've also seen [Functional assertion in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970145/functional-assertion-in-scala/15972055#15972055), but while the idea itself looks interesting, I think `PartialFunction` is not very suitable for the purpose as it is, because often more than one argument is passed and tuples look like a hack in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Option` or `Either` is definitely the way to go for functional programming.

With `Option` it is important to document *why* `None` might be returned.

With `Either`, the left side is the unsuccessful value (the "error"), while the right side is the successful value. The left side does not necessarily have to be an `Exception` (or a subtype of it), it can be a simple error message `String` (type aliases are your friend here) or a custom data type that is suitable for you application.

As an example, I usually use the following pattern when error handling with `Either`:

```scala
// Somewhere in a package.scala
type Error = String // Or choose something more advanced
type EitherE[T] = Either[Error, T]

// Somewhere in the program
def fooMaybe(...): EitherE[Foo] = ...
```

`Try` should only be used for wrapping *unsafe* (most of the time, plain Java) code, giving you the ability to pattern-match on the result:

```scala
Try(fooDangerous()) match {
   case Success(value) => ...
   case Failure(value) => ...
}
```

But I would suggest only using `Try` locally and then go with the above mentioned data types from there.

Some advanced datatypes like `cats.effect.IO` or `monix.reactive.Observable` contain error handling natively.

I would also suggest looking into [`cats.data.EitherT`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html) for typeclass-based error handling. Read the documentation, it's definitely worth it.

---

As a sidenote, for everyone coming from Java, Scala treats all `Exception`s as Java treats `RuntimeException`s. That means, even when an unsafe piece of code from one of your dependencies throws a (checked) `IOException`, Scala will never require you to `catch` or otherwise handle the exception. So as a rule of thumb, when using Java - dependencies, almost always wrap them in a `Try` (or an `IO` if they execute side effects or block the thread).

Comment: I have to disagree with your advice on `Try`. This is just a more verbose and slower version of `try-catch` without any corresponding benefit. Like writing `if (Option(x).isDefined)` instead of `if (x != null)`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I understand your argument of verbosity. However I strongly disagree. With Scala, whenever you can make something type safe, you should do so. Your example of `Option` is actually the best one in favor: Noone forces you to check that `x` is not `null`, and the compiler will not complain when attempting to access a field on a variable that is `null`. With `Option`, you don't even have access to value unless you use `map`, `flatMap` or `foreach` (which is nullsafe) or explicitly use `get`. `Try` is very similar. You are forced to handle both cases by the compiler, avoiding bugs.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I had both experiences, both Java projects where everything was working with reflection and nullable variables, and Scala projects where the final program is a composition of many `IO`s that automatically allocate and deallocate resources, handle errors and lazily stream data throughout the application, without a single `var` or `null` in sight. I know what I prefer.

Comment: I am not objecting to using `Try` at all, but to using it only to match on the result immediately. And my problem is exactly that it doesn't actually make anything more type-safe.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov How come? `value` and `error` are typed. The strong type signature also allows `cats` to implement type classes like `Applicative` on it, giving you the ability to use `mapN`, for example. Or when you realize that the code inside the `Try` executes side effects, you can simply switch out the `Try` for an `IO`, without even changing any of the code depending on it, because you can just use the type classes.

Comment: "giving you the ability to use mapN" That would not be "matching on the result immediately" and is a good reason to use `Try`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I mean mondaic composition in general - giving you the power to modulary compose your program without any code refactoring. You don't get that stuff with `try-catch`. So, just use `Try` right away so you can later abstract over your code.

Comment: Of course. To reiterate, my objection is restricted to what you recommend in the answer: `Try(fooDangerous()) match { ... }`. It's this specific case where I claim there's no benefit.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I see your point. I would still argue the benefit to be that you can later easily write more than just a `match` without having to refactor.

Answer (score 5):

I think your reasoning is correct. If you have a simple total (opposite of partial) function with arguments that can have invalid types *then the most common and simple solution is to return some optional result* like `Option`, etc.

It's usually not advisable to throw exceptions as they break FP laws. You can use any library that can return a more advanced type than `Option` like Scalaz `Validation` if you need to compose results in ways that are awkward with `Option`.

Another two alternatives I could offer is to use:

1. Type constrained arguments that enforce preconditions. Example: `val i: Int Refined Positive = 5` based on https://github.com/fthomas/refined. You can also write your own types which wrap primitive types and assert some properties. The problem here is if you have arguments that have multiple interdependent valid values which are mutually exclusive per argument. For instance `x > 1 and y < 1` or `x < 1 and y > 1`. In such case you can return an optional value instead of using this approach.
2. Partial functions, which in the essence resemble optional return types: `case i: Int if i > 0 => ...`. Docs: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/PartialFunction.html.

For example:
PF's `def lift: (A) ⇒ Option[B]` converts PF to your regular function.

> Turns this partial function into a plain function returning an Option
>   result.

Which is similar to returning an option. The problem with partial functions that they are a bit awkward to use and not fully FP friendly.

I think `Predef.require` belongs to very rare cases where you don't want to allow any invalid data to be constructed and is more of a stop-everything-if-this-happens kind of measure. Example would be that you get arguments you never supposed to get.

Comment: Good answer. Cats also provides [`Validated`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html). The documentation nicely shows what the problem is and how `Validated` is solving it.

Answer (score 2):

You use the return type of the function to indicate the type of the result.
If you want to describe a function that can fail for whatever reason, of the types you mentioned you would probably return `Try` or `Either`: I am going to "try" to give your a result, or I am going to return "either" a success or an failure.
Now you can specify a custom exception

```
case class ConditionException(message: String) extends RuntimeException(message)
```

that you would return if your condition is not satisfied, e.g

```scala
import scala.util._
def myfunction(a: String, minLength: Int): Try[String] = {
  if(a.size < minLength) {
    Failure(ConditionException(s"string $a is too short")
  } else {
    Success(a)
  }
}
```

and with Either you would get

```scala
import scala.util._
def myfunction(a: String, minLength: Int): Either[ConditionException,String] = {
  if(a.size < minLength) {
    Left(ConditionException(s"string $a is too short")
  } else {
    Right(a)
  }
}
```

Not that the `Either` solution clearly indicates the error your function might return